# Zsh is treating a string as a filename pattern and complaining about it (NOMATCH option)

Tags: zsh

I'm trying out Zsh, coming from Bash. I was having a bit of trouble to understand why Zsh complains about a grep regex.

```
usr@rk1 ~ % tty | grep ^/dev/tty[1-7]$ > /dev/null 2>&1
zsh: no matches found: ^/dev/tty[1-7]$
```

I noticed the output disappears and all is well if (1) I wrap the regex inside quotation marks, (2) remove the slashes from the regex or (3) use `setopt NO_NOMATCH`.

From zshoptions manual:

> NOMATCH (+3) <C> <Z>
>
> If a pattern for filename generation has no matches, print an error, instead of leaving it unchanged in the argument list. This also applies to file expansion of an initial '~' or '='.

So, it seems to me the regex is being treated as a filename pattern because of the slashes. Is this considered normal or a bug?

Also, It would be great to have something similar to GreyCat's Bashism and BashPitfalls pages but for Zsh. Do you know such resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option, the pattern `^something` is used for filename generation. From the *zshexpn* man page:

> `^x`     (Requires  EXTENDED_GLOB  to  be set.)  Matches anything except
>   the pattern x.  This has a higher precedence
>                 than `/`, so `^foo/bar` will search directories in `.` except `./foo` for a file named `bar`.

So, `^/dev/tty[1-7]$` is trying to find in every sub directory (nothing is excluded, because `^` is followed directly by `/`) of the current directory for a file named `dev/tty1$`, `dev/tty2$`, ..., `dev/tty7$` as `[1-7]` matches exactly one character in the range between 1 and 7. `$` isn't treated special in that case.

You found already the solution, set `NO_NOMATCH` (might be dangerous, but I like it very much as I'm lazy in typing `;)`) or quote (single or double quotes) the caret.

Try with `print` what's happening:

```
$ setopt nomatch extended_glob
$ echo ^/dev/tty[1-7]$
zsh: no matches found: ^/dev/tty[1-7]$

# ^ is doing filename generation in every sub-dir
$ touch foo/dev/tty5$
$ echo ^/dev/tty[1-7]$
foo/dev/tty5$

# quote to prevent filename generation
$ echo "^/dev/tty[1-7]$"
^/dev/tty[1-7]$
$ echo '^/dev/tty[1-7]$'
^/dev/tty[1-7]$
```

Without `EXTENDED_GLOB` set, the caret is interpreted literally as a normal character. So quoting is your friend again -- this times only the `[1-7]` triggers the filename generation:

```
$ setopt nomatch no_extended_glob
$ echo ^/dev/tty[1-7]$
zsh: no matches found: ^/dev/tty[1-7]$

# quote to prevent filename generation
$ echo ^/dev/tty"[1-7]"$
^/dev/tty[1-7]$

# caret is interpreted literally
$ mkdir ^/dev -p
$ touch ^/dev/tty5$
$ echo ^/dev/tty[1-7]$
^/dev/tty5$
```

So, summing up: Quoting of regex pattern seems always a good idea to me -- although I usually also try to save some keystrokes.

Comment: Hi. According to `set -o` I have `extendedglob off`.

Comment: @Samuel: Interesting... in that case the caret is treated literally; I extended my answer accordingly.